# Get "total editing time" from batch of Word documents

Tags: microsoft-word, powershell

Hi I would like to automatically collect the total editing times from many Word .docx documents located in specified folder. Is it even possible e.g. through Powershell to read such properties of Word document?

Comment: Possible duplicate, [Programmatically access document properties for Word 2007 documents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638358/programmatically-access-document-properties-for-word-2007-documents)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and if you're willing to poke at file internals, you don't even have to install Word on the computer that's doing the poking! Word documents are actually ZIP files with a bunch of little files inside. In the `docProps` folder, there's an `app.xml` file that holds various document properties. The total editing time (in minutes) is in the `<TotalTime>` element inside the `<Properties>` element.

I wrote this PowerShell script to add up the times for each DOCX file in the current directory:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
$totalmins = 0
dir -File | ? {$_.Extension -like '.docx'} | % {
    $zip = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::Open($_.FullName, 'Read')
    $propsentry = $zip.GetEntry('docProps/app.xml')
    If ($propsentry -ne $null) {
        $stream = $propsentry.Open()
        $reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader $stream
        $content = $reader.ReadToEnd()
        $xmldoc = [xml]$content
        $totalmins += $xmldoc.Properties.TotalTime
    }
    $zip.Dispose()
}
$totalmins
```

The interesting parts just use .NET's [`ZipFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx) class to poke around inside the document, then it converts the target file's content into an XML document, gets the number, and adds it to the `$totalmins` variable, which is printed out at the very end.